# R - Comparing logical test across multiple columns in a data frame

Tags: r, data-science

I have a data.frame similar to the following example:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
  date.1 = c('2012-05-13','2012-02-09','2013-05-20'),
  date.2 = c('2011-01-01','2012-07-16','2013-09-09'),
  date.3 = c('2012-05-13','2011-03-11','2014-03-10'),
  date.test = c('2014-05-13','2010-05-13','2012-04-13'))
```

In reality, there are hundreds of date fields. For each row in the data.frame, I would like to compare all the date fields to the value in date.test, and if any of the dates are greater than date.test, a single value of TRUE or 1 should be returned.

So the above example should return FALSE, TRUE,TRUE

I've tried

```
DF1[,1:3] > DF1$date.test
```

and get a variety of errors

Cheers for pointing me in the right direction

Also to clarify, since original posting I managed to solve the question with the following:

```
DF1$answer <- DF1$date.1>DF1$date.test | DF1$date.2>DF1$date.test |   DF1$date.3>DF1$date.test
```

However, that would be really clunky if I had to do it for 150+ date fields. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert the `factor` class to `Date` class before doing any comparison.  Loop through the columns of dataset (`lapply(..`) can convert to `Date` class.  Here, it is easy as the `format` is same as the `Date` class format, so just use `as.Date` and assign the output back to original dataset.

```
DF1[] <- lapply(DF1, as.Date)
```

Now, comes the comparison between equal sized datasets.  Replicate the 4th column to make the lengths same as the first 3 columns.  Here, we are using `col(DF1[1:3])`) so that the index returned by this will make the last column elements to replicate.

```
i1 <- DF1[1:3] > DF1[4][col(DF1[1:3])]
i1
#     date.1 date.2 date.3
#[1,]  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
#[2,]  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
#[3,]  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
```

We can convert the logical matrix to a logical `vector` by getting the column sums  (`colSums`) and checking whether it is greater than 0.

```
DF1$answer <- unname(colSums(i1)>0)
DF1$answer
$[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The first part about converting to date class makes perfect sense. I'm not following the second part, but I did add a clarification to my original question because I had a word missing before which made the question unclear.

Comment: @Tomo  I updated the second part.  In fact, earlier it was not clear to me.  Now, after getting the logical matrix, get the `sum` for each column and check if it is greater than 0